# Meaning of “au train où vont les choses”

Tags: expressions, sens

> […] mais au train où allaient les choses […]

I couldn't find the different pieces of this as expressions or idioms or anything. I can't seem to parse any meaning out of it.

Comment: *Au train où vont les choses, les choses où vont les trains vont bientôt cesser d'être des gares.* — Pierre Dac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See other answers for more detail, but the quick answer is that the English equivalent is "At this rate...", or "At the rate things are/were going..."

Answer (score 6):

To me, just saying *this way* doesn't give the temporal meaning of the idiom.

To understand it fully, one must see that this idiom is related to the meaning of the word *train* which is (in french) synonym of *allure, rythme, cadence, vitesse* (see III. in [the CNRTL definition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/train)).

There are many idioms with this very meaning of *pace*, *speed* or maybe *rate*, like *aller bon train* (= *to go quite fast*), or *aller à un train d'enfer* (= *to go extremely fast*).

> Au train où vont les choses, vous aurez terminé plus tôt que prévu !

...could be translated to

> If things keep going on this quickly, you'll be more than on time !

But the nature of the pace (fast or slow) is implicitly deducted from the context. It could just also be :

> Au train où vont les choses, vous n'y serez jamais à temps !

... meaning ...

> If things keep going on this slowly, you'll never be there on time !

Comment: I'm adding one, just to complicate matters… *avoir un train d'avance*.

Answer (score 2):

It means *if things keep going on this way*, or according to [larousse.com](http://www.larousse.com/en)

> *Au train où vont les choses*, si la situation continue d'évoluer de la même façon. ([Phrase : **train**](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionnaires/francais/train/78943/locution))

And to the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/)

> *Au train où l'on va; au train/du train où vont les choses; au train où va le monde, la science; à ce train-là.* Si l'on continue, si quelque chose continue ainsi. ([**train** III A 3 c](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/train))

It may¹ convey a meaning of pace, too. As in *if things keep on **at this pace***, but I think that it is not that important, for instance both could be glosed *si ça continue comme ça*.

Even if according to [someone from my dear LIMSI](http://perso.limsi.fr/Individu/gs/DLF/Eviter.html) it should be *du train dont vont les choses*

> Du train dont vont les choses (et non au train où vont les choses, qui ne veut rien dire).

---

<sub>1. Merci, [Romain](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2834/82).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

D'après le Robert, parmi les différents sens et emplois de *train*, pour ce qui concerne le déroulement d'une action :

> Vieilli 
> *train* :  Manière d'aller, d'évoluer, marche (des choses).
>
> Moderne
>  ***Du*** train **où** vont les choses : si les choses continuent comme cela. 
>   
>  ***Au*** train **dont** va la science (Bergson).

**EDIT**

> - **Du train** :
>    *train* correspond à une file d'objets (ou d'animaux) en mouvement qui suivent un pilote ou une motrice. 
>    On pourrait dire : « à la vitesse à laquelle le train avance et en considérant les éléments qui le constituent ».
> - **Au train** :
>     *train* est pris dans le sens de rythme,  sens *Vieilli* ci-dessus.